# smartest way for doing a query by orm to a model where a n:m relationship is involved

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, relationship

I need to extract some datas from a table;

[image: leves -----n-----m---company_levels----m---n---company]

the cleanest way:

```
    $levels = Cga_company_level::where(['company_uuid' => $companyUuid])->get()->pluck('cgaLevel');
```

the second cleanest way:

```
            $levels = Cga_company_level::where(['company_uuid' => $companyUuid])->get();
            $levelIds= $companyLevelsByUuids->pluck('cga_level_id');
            $levels= Cga_level::whereIn('cga_level_id',$levelIds)->get();
```

the old school way:

```
$companyLevelsByUuids = Cga_company_level::where(['company_uuid' => $companyUuid])->with('cgaLevel')->get();
$levels = [];
foreach ($companyLevelsByUuids as $companyLevel) {
         $level = $companyLevel->cgaLevel;
         $levels[] = $level;
}
```

any other smartest way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `levels` relationship to get it through a different way but it might not necessarily be more efficient. Plus, you'll be finding the company through the Id or alternatively use `whereUuid($companyUuid)->first()` in the following query:

```
$levels = Company::find($companyId)->levels->get()->pluck('cga_level_id');
```

Comment: levels is not defined directly on company models, do you mean that i need a "Has Many Through" on this nmodel?

Comment: Not really, just a normal `Many to Many` relationship since the middle table is just a pivot table. I could be misunderstanding your DB